# Get and Send messages through amazon api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

My company is working with the amazon MWS api, and we are receiving a lot of messages from the customers about their orders.

Is there any way to get these messages using the web services and reply to them?

Comment: did you manage to do this?

Comment: @coder771 I gave up and i'm not working in the same company anymore.

Amazon don't provide solutions for that to avoid their customers to get automatic answers.

Comment: Tip: You can handle special message titles like 'Cancellation request' and put that order on hold (or whatever you do) so it won't ship if customer service is out for lunch. But watch out because sometimes they have different subject wording for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @joshubrown pointed out correctly, there currently is no API to get customer messages or send replies. You can, however set up a separate mail account for that purpose, which (depending on your own server architecture) gives you a whole set of protocols like POP3, IMAP, SMTP or even MAPI. Regular emails sent to the "scrambled" customer email addresses will be relayed to the consumer and will shown up as replies in your Seller Central.

Comment: Is it possible to send emails to customers from the merchant account? I don't mean to get their replies or send replies, but to send an original email to each customer and have the sender appear as the Amazon merchant.

Comment: @pez It is possible though probably not advisable. You could use any mass mailing software to send mails through SMTP. For good reasons, Amazon does not like that sort of behaviour.

Comment: Could you point me toward the part of the API which makes this possible, if you know? If we use SMTP, could we still list it as coming from our marketplace account? I personally received an email from an Amazon merchant that had the sender's email listed as a scrambled address @marketplace.amazon.com, which is what we'd like to do.

Comment: @pez. Any mail sent to one of those scrambled email addresses will be relayed by Amazon on your behalf

Comment: @Hazzit how to set order reference? I m sending email with sendgrid

Comment: @ant I'm not sure. You may be able to parse the order reference in incoming mails, I don't think you can set an order reference in outgoing mails. I may be wrong, though. Check the incoming mail headers, they might have additional info.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a public API for that.

Comment: but how do big companies do?
I mean, the purpose of the task is to answer automatically to clients. How can i manage it?

Comment: @d3cima did you manage to do this? How reply manager zendesk does this? any idea

Answer (score 1):

How I was planning to do this (in the absence of an API) was to set up the email account (that would receive the emails from customers) such that it pipes the email content into a script. The script would then write the content to the database (or do whatever you want with it).

I'm using qmail for mail, and if you edit the .qmail file within an email account's folder you can set where to pipe the email content eg

```
| php /pathtoscript/emailHandlingScript.php
```

Other email systems will have a different syntax for this.

Then in your PHP code (if you're using PHP), you can grab the content from the stdin stream:

```
$fh = fopen('php://stdin')
```

I'll probably use PHP's mailparse functions (eg mailparse_msg_parse_file, mailparse_msg_get_part etc) to properly extract the data from the stream.

As @Hazzit points out, when you reply to the anonymised email address (eg qwugwquigduwqgiqwdgiuwqdg@amazon.co.uk), Amazon will pass it on to the customer.

Comment: how to set order reference?

Comment: You need to parse the email for the order reference.

Answer (score 1):

I created users on my account, redirected mails and made a script to read and reply.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the script which actually parses the email content? I can successfully get the content in my php script but don't have enough experience with regex etc to parse it to meaningful parts (like order id, content of the message)